# jQuery calculate height for responsive menu

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've got a sticky menu that goes to position: absolute and top: 0 when you scroll past it. In mobile resolutions I hope to stack the items on top of one another, but still sticky it to the top. It's a single page website with a nav and anchor links, when you click an item, you scroll down the page to the desired location.

My jQuery is correctly detecting the heigh of the NAV and then putting a bottom margin on the HEADER element, but I'm struggling to work out how to scroll down to the anchor point, but add the height of the NAV to the top so that the menu doesn't overlap the top of the target area.

Does this make sense?

Look at http://littleamsterdam.co/new/ in a desktop, shrink down to a mobile resolution and scroll down past the header, then click any of the nav buttons to see what I mean.

Comment: Have you written any jQuery, or are you still relying on default anchor behavior? I'd look at the many scroll-to examples here on SO, and add the height of your mobile menu to theme as needed depending on screen size.

Comment: I'm using the default anchor behaviour right now. Would rather not use a plugin if I can get away with writing something simple but I don't even know how I should build it using jQuery / JS TBH..

Comment: You'll need to do some research and come back when you have a more specific question. There's a ton of good info to be had.